# JQuery. Плавная прокрутка исключая элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне надо исключить из кода прокрутку с внутренних ссылок, в которых присутствует `id=...`:

```
$("a[href*=\\#]:not([id=\\#pills-home-tab])").on("click", function (e) {
    var anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 777);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Прокрутка не исключила элемент:

```
<a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Материалы</a>
```

из прокрутки.

Как правильно прописать условие в скрипте?

Comment: Сделал так
$("a[href*=\\#]").not(".nav-link").on("click", function (e) {
        var anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 777);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
Но хотелось бы ещё  увидеть решение с любым из атрибутов, указанных в ссылке

Comment: $("a[href*=\\#]:not(a[href=#pills-home-tab])")

Comment: Почему не использовать селектор по классу для on-click?

Comment: $("a[href*=\\#]:not(a[href=#pills-home-tab])")  не работает. Ошибки. Сделал так $("a[href*=\\#]:not(a[href=\\#pills-home-tab])") . Ошибок нет но крутит по всем ссылкам не исключая данную

Comment: Почему не использовать селектор по классу для on-click? - Да, Вы правы, самый простой путь :-)  Но хотелось бы всё-таки понять как тут можно с атрибутами работать правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал

```
$("a[href*=\\#]:not([role=\'tab\'])").on("click", function (e) {...}
```

Всем спасибо!